# Animate button two Labels Text change

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

Here the issue is , when i was tap the button the two labels text will be change,but i'm not able to display that animated function here the my code,

```
CABasicAnimation *rotate =
    [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotate.byValue = @(M_PI*1); // Change to - angle for counter clockwise rotation
    rotate.duration = 0.4;

    [_button.layer addAnimation:rotate
                            forKey:@"myRotationAnimation"];




    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.type = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    [_name1.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];
    [_name2.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];

    // Change the text
    _from.text = @"new 222text";

    _to.text = @"new text";
```

but i want change like this,

[image]

When i tapped that arrow button ,from and to address will be change up and down animation.Can you please help me ,i'm trying but i can not figure out like that,Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method for text change for the labels while button action,

```
bool isShown = false;
```

In the button Action :

```
- (IBAction)textChange:(id)sender {

    if (!isShown) {
            from.frame =  CGRectMake(31, 220, 217 , 38);
            to.frame =  CGRectMake(31, 275, 217 , 38);

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                from.frame =  CGRectMake(31, 275, 217, 38);
                to.frame =  CGRectMake(31, 220, 217 , 38);

            }];
            isShown = true;
        } else {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
                from.frame =  CGRectMake(31, 220, 217, 38);
                to.frame =  CGRectMake(31, 275, 217, 38);

            }];
            isShown = false;
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to animate your label:

```
- (CAAnimation*)moveup;
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    animation.keyPath = @"position.y";
    animation.fromValue = @-500;
    animation.toValue = @10;
    animation.duration = 0.25;

    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

    [label1.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"basic"];
    [label2.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"basic"];


    label1.layer.position = CGPointMake(0,20);
    label2.layer.position = CGPointMake(0,20);

    return animation;

}
```

and add the dimention parameter according to your need.
hope this will work fine.

you can rotate through this code:

```
-(CAAnimation*)rotate
{
    CGRect boundingRect = CGRectMake(350, -500, -5,-5);

    CAKeyframeAnimation *orbit = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
    orbit.keyPath = @"position";
    orbit.path = CFAutorelease(CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(boundingRect, NULL));
    orbit.duration =0.5;
    orbit.additive = YES;
    orbit.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    orbit.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    orbit.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;

    [btnScan.layer addAnimation:orbit forKey:@"orbit"];
    return orbit;
}
```

Comment: please change the position of x and y.